# Android. Определение координат

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

Как определить координаты по запросу?

К примеру, сейчас я координаты узнаю так:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);

 private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
};
```

Но тут есть одна загвоздка, он будет вызывать подписку на событие - locationListener, в зависимости от изменения моих координат или по времени.

Мне этого не надо. Я хочу, один раз получить координаты и дальше с ними работать, при необходимости получить еще раз.

Если передать в параметры время = 0 и метры = 0, то он просто будет максимально часто обновлять координаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с API 9 есть прекрасный метод `requestSingleUpdate(...)` у `LocationManager` для таких целей.
Либо обратите внимание на `getLastKnownLocation(...)`.